# How to get mongol working in the browser?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Ok so I installed the Mongol plugin, it's not yet showing up in my browser. How do I make that happen?

On installation the console suggested I remove the autopublish package, I did, it did not help, but it did stop my app updating in the browser so I re-added it.

Comment: As stated in the [Mongol doc](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol/#plug--play-installation), accessing the Mongol magicness is with CTRL+M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add back autopublish with:

```
$meteor add autopublish
```

To make Mongol appear, use the shortcut `ctl` + `m`

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the first part as soon as I'd posted, haha. But thanks to you I have mongol appearing. It's amazing! like a compact phpMyAdmin but better :D haha

Answer (score 2):

Mongol configures automatically. To get started, simply run:

$ meteor add msavin:mongol

After installation, press Control + M to toggle it.

Other details at https://github.com/msavin/Mongol